# javascript execution failing in java with XPathResult undefined

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

I'm trying to execute the javascript function with java, and I'm getting an error message that it is not able to find some of the classes. can someone please help me to clear this issue?

***My Java class***

```
public class TestException {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager engineMgr=new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine=engineMgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        Document doc=HtmlPage.getHTML("", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\PHPTRAVELS.html", "https://phptravels.com");
        String xpath="//input";
        
        //for single value
    /*  String jscript="return document.evaluate('"+xpath+"',document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;";
        WebElement element=(WebElement)jse.executeScript(jscript);
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("name"));*/
        
        String multiCode="var test=function(document){"
                + "var results=document.evaluate('//input', document,null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);"+
                "var tagNames = [];\r\n"
                + "var count=0;" +
                "while(node = results.iterateNext()) {\r\n" + 
                "  count=count+1;" + 
                "}"
                + "\r\n return count}";
        /*FileWriter fileWrite=new FileWriter(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\jScript.js"));
        fileWrite.write(multiCode);
        fileWrite.flush();
        fileWrite.close();*/
        
        try{
            engine.eval(multiCode);
            Invocable invc=(Invocable) engine;
            Long count=(Long)invc.invokeFunction("test", doc);
        //Long count=(Long) jse.executeScript(multiCode);
        System.out.println(count);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

***Exception***

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "XPathResult" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:392)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
    at demo.TestException.main(TestException.java:58)
Caused by: <eval>:1 ReferenceError: "XPathResult" is not defined
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.__noSuchProperty__(Global.java:1441)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$1$27A$\^eval\_.test(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:639)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:386)
```

please let me know if data required from my side.

Comment: Maybe the DOM is not loaded when the script is run or you might not have the results for  XPath

Comment: "The XPathResult interface represents the results generated by evaluating an XPath expression within the context of a given node. Since XPath expressions can result in a variety of result types, this interface makes it possible to determine and handle the type and value of the result"

Comment: I have done the debugging also but i didn't found any issue with the code.. and `multicode` String in the code which i'm trying to execute.

Comment: Did you try with a different xpath other than `//input`?

Comment: Yes i have tried but i'm getting `XapthResult` is not defined

Comment: Maybe the document loaded is not a valid HTML or XML file. I'm out of ideas...

Comment: `String testCode="var demo=function(document){return document.getElementById('address');}";` i have tried with this function and i'm able to got the result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are using `XPathResult` which present under `window` object, `window` object implementation is provided by the web browser. Nashorn (ScriptEngine) doesn't provide `window` implementation.

From Java Docs:

> While Oracle Nashorn runs ECMA-compliant JavaScript, it is important to note that objects normally accessible in a web browser are not available, for example, console, window, and so on.

You can execute and verify your js code with Nashorn using `jjs` option:

```
> jjs test.js
abc.js:2 ReferenceError: "XPathResult" is not defined
```

As you want to parse the HTML file, you can achieve it by using HTML parser such as https://jsoup.org/ , if are using this code for testing you can use Selenium's API `JavascriptExecutor#executeScript(...)`

Comment: Yes i'm aware of jsoup, what exactly i'm trying to do is what ever the xpath i will pass should be validate by document and get the count of matching results,, for this in jsoup there is no method available to validate xpath.. so i'm trying to use this one

Comment: @SatishRongala if I am not wrong, you are trying to find the count of a number of `input` fields right? Add more details to the question on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to find the number of input fields in the web page by using the xpath

Comment: You can search and count `input` tags using jsoup. But if you strictly wants to use XPath based searching try https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup

Comment: i will check the reference link and if it solve my problem.. i will accept/upvote to your comment

Comment: Thank you Govinda, XSoup resolved the issue but i want to put some important information that XSoup dev have stopped long back ago.. So who ever referring thisanswer please use the xsoup with jsoup 1.11.3 version otherwise you will get exception